# SQL to Reformat Timestamp Field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using Java and SQL to query a table in BigQuery. I want to achieve the following:

- Pull Table
- Reformat a String (ex. Jan 08 2018) to a Timestamp (ex. 2018-01-08 23:59:28 UTC)
- Push all the new data back to either a new or existing table

At the moment, I'm successfully pulling the table with:

```
QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
            QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
                    "SELECT *"
                      + "FROM `MyTable` "
                      + "LIMIT 10")
                    .setUseLegacySql(false)
                    .build();
```

Is it possible to include a SQL update statement that takes the existing String time field and reformats it to match the Timestamp format? I'm aware that the initial time String doesn't contain enough information to be a Timestamp. I'm okay with the missing values to be 0's (ex. 00:00:00 UTC)

Comment: All the values in that field follow Jan 08 2018 format. I do intend to apply the same logic to other fields in the future once I figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to include a SQL update statement that takes the existing String time field and reformats it to match the Timestamp format?

See below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Jan 08 2018' AS date_as_string
)
SELECT date_as_string, PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d %Y', date_as_string) date_as_timestamp
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row date_as_string  date_as_timestamp    
1   Jan 08 2018     2018-01-08 00:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when I try that: Unexpected string literal 'myTable` AS ( ...'.

My code is: 
"WITH 'myTable` "
         + "AS ( SELECT time AS dateS)"
         + "SELECT dataS, PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d %Y', dateS) dateT"
         + "FROM 'myTable' "
         + "LIMIT 10")

I can't seem to format it in a comment, so I apologize if it's hard to read.

Comment: I don't see any use of `myTable in my example  - can you clarify what it is that you are running!

Comment: oh, i see now - check use of apostrophe on left side of myTable - it should be tick instead

Comment: myTable is just the name of the table I'm referencing in BQ. It is formatted correctly in my actual code.

Comment: see my comment about wrong use of apostrophe on left side of myTable string

Comment: you can put you actual script in your question - so format will be properly presented!

Comment: meantime - have you run example as it is in my answer? did it worked as you expected? - as this is actually what was the question that I answered :o)

Comment: Ahh good eye. I tried running both my script and yours. It now returns "Syntax error: Unexpected identifier `project.dataset.table` "

Comment: Okay, I'll update the script in my question to show what I'm trying to run

Comment: if you are trying to apply my answer to your data  - you need to provide your project, dataset and table delimited with dots and wrapped with ticks as it is in my example!

Comment: still - were you able to run example in my answer from within BQ UI?

Comment: It ran successfully in BigQuery UI. I can't seem to get it right in my code though.

Comment: so your current question (Is it possible to include a SQL update statement that takes the existing String time field and reformats it to match the Timestamp format?) is answered I would recommend you to post new question specific to your new issue/problem - and someone will answer. On SO many-in-one type of questions are not appreciated

Comment: meantime, consider voting up the answer if it helped anyhow and accept it (if you will follow up my suggestion about new question)

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that! Your answer helped a bunch and I think I have enough to figure it out from here. Is there a way to reach out to you through SO later if I have a relevant question. I'm aware of a chat feature, but don't know how to use it properly

Comment: for last many years I am on SO each and every day (as many of us here who ready to help) - so anytime you have a question - just post it  - and believe me you will get the answer in timely manner o:)

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of the BigQuery timestamp related functions [PARSE_TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp) and [FORMAT_TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#format_timestamp) to reformat the timestamp

Comment: Don't they both require a Timestamp as a parameter? Unfortunately, I'm starting out with a String formatted as "MMM dd yyyy"

Comment: If you look at the examples in the link, they use string, so you should be fine

Comment: Thank you Kannappan. Your answer was correct. Mikhail helped me understand how to use it!